# Inverse of the function with complex roots

Tags: calculus

I got this question on my midterm and afterwards found exactly the same one in Stewart Calculus book. The task is to find the inverse of $$f(x) = \sqrt{x^3+x^2+x+1}$$
and then find it's derivative. In the book it's written that I need to use computer algebra system to solve it, but I feel like I can solve it manually since I got it on my exam.

I know that there are 3 roots, 2 of which contain imaginary numbers so we could just drop them in this context.

My question is how to find these roots. Do I need to use substitution when I get $$x^3+x^2+x+1-y^2 = 0$$
or should I express one variable through another?

Any hints and explanation would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x+1)}{x-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^4-1}{x-1}}$ assume $x\neq 1$ and it should be simple to find the roots of the numerator.

Comment: This only says how to find solutions to $f(x)=0$, not to $f(x)=y$ (which you need if you want to compute $f^{-1}(y)$).

Comment: @HansLundmark, yeah, I saw it. Solving further I'm getting stuck on the same step of finding the root. Wolfram Alpha just gives the answer but I want to understand how to do it

Comment: Search for “Cardano's formula”, which gives the solution to cubic equations.

Comment: @HansLundmark, wow, just googled it, thanks